# mysql get all other rows how have same id from same table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables !

Songs:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Title          |         ID       |      Version     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|   songnumber1       |         34       |    original      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|   songnumber2       |         35       |      remix       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|   songnumber3       |         36       |      remix       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

And I have Other table to make references between songs
reference:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         ID          |      remix       |      original    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         1           |        35        |        34        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         2           |        36        |        34        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

What I want is to display the related songs below of the current song
let's say $id is the ID of the current song which is 35
I want to display all other songs remix and the original also
I tried this but it get just the original if $id is remix:

```
SELECT * FROM reference
         INNER JOIN songs ON reference.remix = songs.id OR 
reference.original = songs.id
         WHERE reference.original = '$id' OR reference.remix = '$id'
```

Comment: Can you add the expected result in a tabular format?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM reference r
INNER JOIN songs a ON r.remix = a.ID  
INNER JOIN songs b ON r.original = b.ID
WHERE r.remix = 35
```

It would help if you post the expected results. Maybe this is what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM reference r
INNER JOIN Songs a ON r.remix = a.ID  
WHERE r.remix = 35
UNION  
SELECT * FROM reference r
INNER JOIN Songs b ON r.original = b.ID
WHERE r.remix = 35
```

Comment: Thank you for reply ! I tried this but it's not the solution for this ! I want to show all related content how has same original ID on referance table and show original song same with them

Comment: Can you post in your question a sample of what you want to see?

Comment: I added another option, but I am not sure if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  C.currently_playing, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(C.currently_playing=C.id,C.title,null)) current_song_title, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(C.version='original',C.id,null)) orignial_song_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(C.version='original',C.title,null)) orignial_song_title, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(C.version='remix',C.id,null)) related_remix_ids, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(C.version='remix',C.title,null)) related_remix_titles 
FROM
  (SELECT 35 AS currently_playing, A.*
   FROM Songs   A 
   RIGHT JOIN (SELECT * FROM `references` WHERE remix=35 or original=35) B
   ON A.id IN (B.original,B.remix)) C
GROUP BY C.currently_playing;
```

See a working [Demo on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5372a/20).